# How to convert byte string to a text file?

Tags: python, stringio

I'm trying to run this code. It is giving me the output in bytes. I want to know how to convert bytes to a text file

```
def convert(fname,pages):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        pagenums = set(str(pages))

    output = StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    infile = open(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close
    return text
```

Comment: if you only want to read a file and get values you can use `open(fname, 'r')`, alse refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm for details